# Extracting particular data using pdftotext

Tags: python, text, data-extraction, pdftotext

I am using pdftotext Python Library to extract some data from a PDF Document.

```
import pdftotext

# Load your PDF
with open("text2.pdf", "rb") as f:
    pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)


# How many pages?
print(len(pdf))



data = "\n\n".join(pdf)
# Read all the text into one string
print(data)
```

The data extracted is:

```
Account Name               :Mr. SX
Account Name               :Mr. XX XX XX
Address                  : Address detaisls
                      
Date                        :7 Sep 2021
Account Number               :00000031873583221
Account Description          :REGULAR SB CHQ-INDIVIDUALS
Branch                      :SSI 
Drawing Power               :0.00
```

The whole data is in string but I want to extract only the Account Number.
I used regex expresion:

```
^(Account\s+Number).*$
```

But unable to figure out how to extract the data from the whole string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
>>> '\n'.join([re.sub(r'Account Number\s+:', '', line) for line in data.splitlines() if 'Account Number' in line])
'00000031873583221'
>>>
```

Easier without regex:

```
>>> '\n'.join([line.split(':')[-1] for line in data.splitlines() if 'Account Number' in line])
'00000031873583221'
>>>
```